# LWC - Local Development Server

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, sfdx-plugin, lightning-development

Any updates about the Local dev server which was supposed to be out in beta probably this month based on the recorded webinar session I saw: https://developer.salesforce.com/event/local-development-lightning-web-components

Otherwise also I am trying to get a good understanding about the way the development would work because I have different pieces of the puzzle but do not yet know how to approach to wire everything to be up and running with LWC development.

Any pointer will be very helpful. (I have actually done the recipes, playground and trailheads individually over a period of time stretching over 3-4 months and having a tough time connecting it all together)

Answer (score 2):

@mitesh 
Salesforce has finally release LWC local development

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/announcing-lwc-local-development-beta.html

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2022

The local development for Lightning Web Components still has beta status: [Local Development (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/lwclocaldev)

However, even the beta version can now be used relatively reliably. To set up local development you only need to authorize an org and install the development server. This allows you to develop locally without the need to push your components to an org first.

The local development server and its configuration are provided by a Salesforce CLI plugin that can be installed as follows:

```
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server
```

After installing the plugin, to start the server on `http://localhost:3333` and access all components of the project just run:

```
sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start
```

There is even a short official guide on how to set it up: [Set Up LWC Local Development](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/localdev/set-up-lwc-local-dev)